# How to show window from bottom to top in wpf in animation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

```
static int screenWidth = (int)SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
static int screenHeight = (int)SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;

int heightAvail = ((screenHeight - intHeight) / 2);
int widthAvail = ((screenWidth - intWidth) / 2);
DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(widthAvail, widthAvail, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));
DoubleAnimation animationT = new DoubleAnimation(1920, heightAvail, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));
objUIElement.BeginAnimation(Window.LeftProperty, animation);
objUIElement.BeginAnimation(Window.TopProperty, animationT);
```

This is one I'm using for doing Animation But its coming to center. I want it should stick to bottom of window.

How to achieve this? Please share some ideas.

Comment: Is the solution working for you??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you dividing the `heightAvail` with 2 ??

```
int heightAvail = (screenHeight - intHeight);
```

This should do it.